# No values in loaded option object

Tags: custom-options

When I load custom option that exists, is drop_down type and has values, the $_values property is empty. Any idea why?

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load(1);
var_dump($option->getValues());
//array (size=0)
//empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that the `$_values` attribute that is used by the function `getValues` only contains values specifically set against the object and not those loaded, so it will be empty after load.

But you can get the values collection on a loaded option object as follows.

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load(2);
$values = $option->getValuesCollection();
```

Or you could load the collection itself directly without first loading the option object.

Answer (score 2):

So your first code snippet looks like this.

```
$option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load(1);
```

This tells  Magento ..

> Hey Magento, please load all **product options** with an ID = 1 to
>   variable `$option`

Then Magento will search for a product option which has an id = 1. If that data exist it will return that data. Otherwise it will return an empty data. To be more specific, the table in which Magento search for an entry is `catalog_product_option`. Suppose that there is an entry exist for the specified id, then `$option` will look like this.

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option Object
(
    [_product:protected] => 
    [_options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_valueInstance:protected] => 
    [_values:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/product_option
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/product_option_collection
    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 1
            [product_id] => 25
            [type] => drop_down
            [is_require] => 0
            [sku] => 
            [max_characters] => 
            [file_extension] => 
            [image_size_x] => 0
            [image_size_y] => 0
            [sort_order] => 0
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [option_id] => 1
            [product_id] => 25
            [type] => drop_down
            [is_require] => 0
            [sku] => 
            [max_characters] => 
            [file_extension] => 
            [image_size_x] => 0
            [image_size_y] => 0
            [sort_order] => 0
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

From above output, we can get some points. Important points are

1. `$option` is an object of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`
2. `$option` holds some data. So `$option->getData()` will return a non-empty array.
3. All other properties of `$option` object is empty (examples :`_product`,`_values`)

The third point I have noted above is the key point that we need to look. When you try to print `$option->getValues()`, what magento does is, it returns `_values` property of object. See the method definition

```
//location:app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php
public function getValues()
{
    return $this->_values;
}
```

Now can you guess what will be the output? It will obviously an empty array. Since as you seen above, your object `_value` property is empty.

Now let us load the same option "via" a product. The code snippet will look like this.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(167);
$all_options = $product->getOptions();
foreach ($all_options as  $option) {
    if($value->getOptionId() == 1)
    {
        print_r($option);
    }
}
```

Here product with id=167 holds our option. So first we load tha product. Then we get all its options by calling `$product->getOptions()`. In order to print the option in discussion (ie option with id=1), we have looped through each options and finds that option. If you look on that output, you will become amazed. It will be also on object of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`, but filled with all of its properties. For example `_product` property holds an object class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` which provides all details of product. `_values` property holds an array of objects which of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Value`. Thus it holds all option values in it. Now if you try print_r($option->getValues()), it will return this array.

So in short, the point is, when we load the product option directly, it is not setting other properties of option class. So when try to get those properties using that object will return empty values. But when we get an option through a product, Magento will set all properties of product options for us. So that method such as `$option->getValues()` will give some valuable data.

It is important to understand that, product options are properties of products. That is options do not have an existence if there is any products. So if you need any options, you need to get it "via" product instance.

So if you need to get a particular option, what you need to do is (in general), load the product instance that defines your option. Then get that option through that product.

For example

```
$product_id = 167;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$options = $product->getOptions();
if($options)
{

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo "Option Title :".$option->getDefaultTitle()."(".$option->getOptionId().")\n";
        echo "\tVALUES (as array):\n";
        foreach ($option->getValues() as  $values) {
            print_r($values->getData());
        }

    }
}
```

Suppose product with id 167 has two custom options. One is of type `checkbox` and other one is of type `dropdown`, then the output above code will look like this

```
Option Title :custom checkbox option(3)
VALUES (as array):

    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 7
        [option_id] => 3
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => checkbox option 1
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => checkbox option 1
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )
    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 8
        [option_id] => 3
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => checkbox option 2
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => checkbox option 2
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )
    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 9
        [option_id] => 3
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => checkbox option 3
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => checkbox option 3
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )

Option Title :custom dropdown option(4)
VALUES (as array):

    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 10
        [option_id] => 4
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => option 1
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => option 1
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )
    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 11
        [option_id] => 4
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => option 2
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => option 2
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )
    Array
    (
        [option_type_id] => 12
        [option_id] => 4
        [sku] => 
        [sort_order] => 0
        [default_title] => option 3
        [store_title] => 
        [title] => option 3
        [default_price] => 0.0000
        [default_price_type] => fixed
        [store_price] => 
        [store_price_type] => 
        [price] => 0.0000
        [price_type] => fixed
    )
```

Here as you can see, We are first loading produt that define our custom option. Here I assume that product is with id 167. Then we load its option using `getOptions()` method. Its an array of `options object`. More specifically its an array of objects of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option`. Each of this array holds information about each option that we defined for that products, such as option_id, option_type, option_title etc. Now to retrieve values of each option we need to use `getValues()` on each option object.Then it will return an array of `values object`. Each of this array holds values of that particular option.

Now if you need options without any product loading, you just refer @keyul_shah answer. Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Great answer if my question was "how to load options from a product". However, that was not the case. Why do you think an option with ID = 1 would return an "empty" object?

Comment: there were some error in my answer. Now look my answer and give me feedback

Comment: I think you are completely missing the point of my question. You maybe want to check the comments on the other answer. By the way, I don't really think there is a need for over explaining a question that is very simple.

Comment: did you gone through my answer. It now clearly explains why `getValues()` method didnt work

Comment: You are assuming that _values property was empty. Can you please tell me, how did you get that assumption?

Comment: I think my answer clearly shows why didnt your code output empty and it also provide importance of collecting options via project. I know it is unnecessary for your question. But it may help people that are going through your question

Comment: It is not an assumption. I have provided  output of your code. Check it. Did you notice this part ` [_values:protected] => Array
        (
        )`. That means it is getValues() will return empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15716/discussion-between-programmer-rkt-and-ldusan).

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

To get the Value of your custom attribute then

```
 $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
 print_r($option->getData('Your Attribute ID'));
```

To get the All values

```
 /**
 * @var $config  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
 * @var $options Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection
 */
$storeId   = 3;
$config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');
$values    = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions();
print_r($values);

//here is another method
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
$values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter($storeId)->toOptionArray();
print_r($values);
```

Comment: What I want is to get all the dropdown values for given custom option.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: The question was not how to get values, it was why it does not load values in option object. I am asking this because that getValues() method is used on some other place.

Comment: because you are loading wrong class that's why

Comment: Look at Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Abstract, line 65: foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value)

Comment: In Magento 1.8.1 I Don't getting any code as you mention above. I checked thrice.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ldusan84/8426752#file-gistfile1-php-L65

Comment: This is core file of magento you he got object in $this so in your custom phtml file you have to create object like that and then you can use this options

Comment: Who mentioned custom phtml file? I am applying option renderer and at some point, it calls getValuesHtml(), with $_values being empty, I am just asking why it is empty when it is obviously supposed to work.